# Exception: "No default Constructor provided" exception subclassing ParseObject

Tags: java, android, oop, inheritance, parse-platform

I have two classes `NewsImage` and `EventImage` that are almost identical and therefore they inherit from `Image` abstract class. Each of those two represent a class in my Parse database.

```
public abstract class Image extends ParseObject {

    public Image(){};

    public String getImageId(){
        return getObjectId();
    }

    public void setImageId(String imageId){
        setObjectId(imageId);
    }

    public byte[] getImageBytes(){
        try {
            return getParseFile("image").getData();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void setImageBytes(byte[] bytes){
        put("image", new ParseFile(bytes));
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmap(){
        return Toolbox.ByteArrayToBitmap(getImageBytes());
    }
```

EventImage  Class

```
    @ParseClassName("OSW_event_images")
    public class EventImage extends Image {

        public EventImage() {
            super();

        }

        public Event getEvent(){
            return (Event) getParseObject("event");
        }

        public void setEvent(Event event){
            put("event", event);
        }

    };
```

NewsImage  class

```
    @ParseClassName("OSW_news_images")
    public class NewsImage extends Image {

        public NewsImage() {
            super();

        }

        public News getNews(){
            return (News) getParseObject("news");
        }

        public void setNews(News event){
            put("news", event);
        }

    };

}
```

I register those two classes before I call `Parse.initialize()`

```
ParseObject.registerSubclass(Image.EventImage.class);
ParseObject.registerSubclass(Image.NewsImage.class);
```

After I run this I get:

```
09-19 12:38:39.794: E/AndroidRuntime(25806): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{pl.holdapp.osw/pl.holdapp.osw.activities.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No default constructor provided for class pl.holdapp.osw.objects.Image$EventImage
09-19 12:38:39.794: E/AndroidRuntime(25806):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
```

Comment: problem is that EventImage is not static nested class... it cannot exists without outer Image class instance ... `pl.holdapp.osw.objects.Image$EventImage`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the EventImage class static. As it is now the default constructor needs an implicit reference to the outer class.

Comment: Eventually, I put them both out of my abstract `Image` class but you are certainly right that those classes cannot exist without Image being instantiated.